# Adding two int's

Tags: python, python-2.7, math, integer, addition

why can't I add these together?

```
a = int(input("input a number to add"))
b = int(input("input a number to add"))
a + b = c
print(c)
```

can't assign to operator

Comment: Assuming you're programming in Python, I suggest you start with [the Python beginners guide](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide) and [other Python  documentation](https://www.python.org/doc/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't do `a+b=c` you should do `c=a+b` because you can't give the non existing value c to something named a+b
(when you do `c = a + b` you assign the result of the operation "a+b" in a variable named "c".)